# Any idea to import user defined functions from localhost to live server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import custom user defined function from localhost to live demo server. But it showing this error:

**MySQL said: Documentation 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3**

> ```
> DELIMITER$$  
> CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `isAvailable`(OwnerID INT, DateFrom DATETIME, DateTo DATETIME)  
> RETURNS BIT(1)  
> BEGIN  
> DECLARE t BIT;  
> IF DateFrom IS NULL OR DateTo IS NULL OR EXISTS  (SELECT DateID FROM tbl_name WHERE OwnerID=OwnerID AND ((DateFrom<=DateFrom AND DateFrom<=DateTo) OR (DateFrom<=DateTo AND DateTo<=DateTo)))  
> THEN  
> SET t=0;  
> ELSE  
> SET t=1;     
> RETURN t;  
> END IF;  
> END$$  
> DELIMITER;
> ```

I'm copying from localhost and trying to run on demo server.
Any Idea please where am i wrong??

Comment: Have you tried to use delimiters (DELIMITER command)?

Comment: yes i've tried using DELIMITER but same results.

Comment: The syntax is correct. Please add more information about the problem. Show the code with delimiters. How did you executed the script, or what client do you use?

Comment: I updated my question with delimiter command.

Answer (score 0):

OK got this error. :)
The problem was here **`(DELIMITER$$)`** used this **`(DELIMITER //)`** and also at the end used **`(END //)`** instead this **`(END$$)`**.